# colSum related or similiar function in R alternative to sum in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I am working on converting a complex project implemented in matlab to R. I am having problem converting following code to R (an efficient way)
Matlab:

```
 for r = 1:nSubjects
               temp = reshape(values(r,:),4,10);
               temp = [sum(temp([1 2],:));sum(temp([3 4],:))];
               temp = reshape(temp,1,20);
               X(r,nextCol:(nextCol+19)) = temp;
 end
```

I have tried possible approaches including sum, colSums function. However, I get error

my R code

```
for(r in 1:nSubjects){
          temp = values[1,];
          temp <- matrix(temp, 4, 10);
          colSums(temp[1:2,]) <- this or something similar to do steps 2 & 3 
         }
```

colSums is giving Error in colSums(temp[1:2, ]) : 'x' must be numeric. Not sure how to go about it. Any help is much needed as I am new to R.

Thank you,

Edit: Updating post with requested information (again thank you for help)

Algorithm:
This algorithm is to analyze data that are grouped by 10 set where each set in turn consists of 4 values.
For example below is contents of 1 row in values (variable).

0.100000000000000   0.500000000000000   0.100000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.500000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.100000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.500000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.100000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.100000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.100000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.500000000000000   0.100000000000000   0.600000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.100000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.500000000000000   0.100000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.200000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.300000000000000   0   0.300000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.300000000000000

I want to convert this to a summary like,

0.600000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.700000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.700000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.600000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.600000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.700000000000000   0.700000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.700000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.400000000000000   0.600000000000000   0.300000000000000   0.700000000000000

where each value in above row is sum of 2 consecutive numbers in values (variable name row).

For rows in values
       add consecutive column values, so values has 40 column and it will reduce to 20 cols
       append this summary data row created to a new matrix called temp.
end for

Output of  class(temp)
[1] "matrix"

Comment: Post the result of `dput( values[1,])`. It looks like you may have a data input problem since the error being reported suggests that values is not numeric. (There's probably an easier way to do this, so you might want to spend a bit more effort at describing the algorithm in natural language.)

Comment: A problem I see with your current R code is that `colSums(temp[1:2,])` doesn't get assigned to anything so you might be succeeding inside the `for`-function but not doing anything with the success.

Comment: Can you post the output of  `class(temp)`?